# Celery soft time limit not triggered

Tags: python, exception, scrapy, celery, taskmanager

I have a celery task with a soft limit of 10 and hard limit of 32:

```
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

@app.task(bind=True, acks_late=False, time_limit=32, soft_time_limit=10)
def my_task(self, **kwargs):
    try:
       if 'twisted.internet.reactor' in sys.modules:
            del sys.modules['twisted.internet.reactor']
        settings = get_project_settings()
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        process.crawl(**kwargs)
        process.start()

    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded as te:

        print('Time Exceeded...')
```

The above code executes as expected. However, when crawl takes a long time and the soft limit is reached, exception is not triggered. Crawl continues, then, the hard limit is reached and this error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 684, in on_hard_timeout
    raise TimeLimitExceeded(job._timeout)
billiard.exceptions.TimeLimitExceeded: TimeLimitExceeded(32,)
```

I cannot even catch this error from inside the task. As a test, I replaced `process.start()` command with `time.sleep(50)` so no crawl starts but a long delay is simulted:

```
@app.task(bind=True, acks_late=False, time_limit=32, soft_time_limit=10)
def my_task(self, **kwargs):
    try:
       if 'twisted.internet.reactor' in sys.modules:
            del sys.modules['twisted.internet.reactor']
        settings = get_project_settings()
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        process.crawl(**kwargs)
        time.sleep(50)

    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded as te:
        print('Time Exceeded...')
```

**Then `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` is caught. Why is this the case?**

### Versions

celery==5.2.7

Scrapy==2.6.1

Comment: That makes sense if you are running Celery with gevent pool as gevent doesn't respect soft time limit.

Answer (score 0):

the same issue happened in my side.

I think the most possible is "SoftTimeLimitExceeded" error catch in your script. so it do not raise to the outside.

you can check if there are any Exception expect in your script and remove them or just replace to small scope Exception.

```
 settings = get_project_settings()
 process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
 process.crawl(**kwargs)
```

that's my idea. and I try to do like this. if it works in my side I will keep updating here.

Comment: it do works in my side. maybe you can try:
check any exception catch in your script. between "try" and "except SoftTimeLimitExceeded"
otherwise. it will be catch then solved in your script. can not catch by celery task.